# How can I emigrate to the US without a college degree?

Tags: usa, visa, immigration, canada, australia

I'm 19, I have Italian citizenship and working in Germany as a web developer.
My dream has been to move to the US since I was 12. I won't say much about why it's like that because it would be a long paragraph, but you have to trust me.

I never liked the school system and always felt sad in school, that's why I'm excluding getting a bachelor's degree as an option, although I know that the easiest way would be to get an American job contract and apply for the H-1B visa.

I don't think I'd be able to get married with a US citizen, honestly, so that's another option I'd exclude.

Now I'd like to consider every possible way to get to live there. I registered for the DV lottery this year and I'm hoping for that. Is there any other visa that could help me? Would it be even possible to emigrate to Canada/Australia and be able to emigrate to the US more easily after getting the passport in one of those countries? (or even any other country that could get me to the US)

Comment: The odds on the DV lottery are very low.  Realistically, the only answer in your case is marry an American.

Comment: Increase your IT skills such that you are personally in demand regardless of having a degree or not. Increase your personal prominence so that, for instance, you get asked to speak at conferences on your (future) specialism. You may then be able to get around the degree requirement. Still no guarantee of course, and the work involved will be huge.

Comment: In addition the @user16259 comment, it may be helpful to pick a US employer, or one with US operations, and aim to develop specialized knowledge that they will need in the US.

Comment: Don't see the use of going through another country to get to the US. Just for Canada, it's probably about 2 years to get a permanent residency, then being on Canadian soil for 3 years to qualify for the citizenship request, which takes about a year. That's 6 years to get closer, but still having to go through the whole process for the USA.